# Does a Java Programm substitude a DBMS when connected to a Database

Tags: java, database, relational-database, hsqldb, rdbms

Hey guys im just working on a project with a (relational) HSQL Database. And there the question cropped up: is a Databasemanagementsystem just the swing application that allows me to type in my orders, and do I substitute it when I use my Java Programm to connect to the database and type my orders in there ?

Comment: This is not clear. Eg "substitute" what for what, and what does "susstitute" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

Its about User Experience.

You will create a database considering the rules of normalization and integrity constraints. 
Would you want your front desk users interacting with customers to do following steps so as to create an order :

1. Open an Sql client
2. Connect to proper database.
3. Make up mind to start firing some queries.
4. Create a query to get new customer id as follows :

Select customer_sequence.nextval from dual

5. Create a query to insert customer details in customer table using above generated id.
6. Create a query to generate a order id.

Select order_sequence.nextval from dual

7. Create a query to insert record into order table.
8. Create a query to  insert a record table into order_item table.

.

.

.

.

The list goes on to include features like payment info, delivery details, offers and promotion.

Someone would say one can write a SQL procedure to abstract all these steps. Agree, but you will have to write the code then why not write a GUI application that will ease the order generation process. There are oracle applications that provides Oracle forms to interact with database.But it will be of limited features and would not cater to all requirements that a Java GUI or a Web GUI does.

So, the answer to your question is User experience.